# Get object whose sub-property contains value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Models:

```
public class Header{
    public int ID;
    public int someValue;
    public bool someOtherValue;
    public List<Trailer> Trailers;
}

public class Trailer{
    public int ID;
    public Language MyLanguage;
    public string someDifferentValue;
}
```

In my Controller I hand over multiple objects of type Header to my JavaScript Code. Now I want to go through those Header-Objects and get those Trailers in which several conditions are met. As I found out already there is a JS/jQuery function called "grep" which is used similar to the c# / LINQ .Where().

Let's say I want to get the Header-object where ID equals 1 and the correspondig Trailer in english language:

```
result = jQuery.grep(headerCollection, function(t){
    return jQuery.grep(t.Trailers, function(subT){
        return subT.Language == Language.English
    } && t.ID == 1
}
```

so if I got it right result[0] should be my Header-object and result[0].Trailers[0] should be my corresponding Trailer with English Language.

But as expected it's not working and I couldn't figure out why. Is there a better way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.grep()` returns an array, which is always truthy.

Therefore, calling `grep` in the callback doesn't actually make any sense.

Instead, you should call the built-in [`some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the array, which does what you actually want.

Comment: This seems potentially right but I can't figure out how my code should look like - is it possible for you to give an example?

Comment: @Chill-X: `return t.ID === 1 && t.trailers.some(function(trailer) { return ... })`

Comment: Okay, I'll test this as soon as I'm back @ work. One question - won't return an array true only if there are elements in it? Otherwise it'd be null and therefore return false or am I missing something?

Comment: It will return false if there are no matching elements.

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately it's not working - I think I'm doing something wrong: 
    test = jQuery.grep(e.Actions, function (t) {
                  return !t.IsEnabled && t.Trailer.some(function (tSub) {
        return tSub.Language.ID == e.Language.ID
    })
      })[0].Text

Comment: @Chill-X: Why not? What's the problem? Did you try debugging?

Comment: My point of view was totally wrong, I wanted something completely different from what I've asked here - but regarding this question your answer fully fits it. Thank you!

Comment: You probably wanted to filter the child arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There are missing parentheses:

```
result = jQuery.grep(headerCollection, function(t){
    return jQuery.grep(t.Trailers, function(subT){
        return subT.Language == Language.English
    }) && t.ID == 1
})
```